# Where is this equation coming from?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm given a problem and I've finished the problem, but I was just wondering where we are getting an equation from. The problem is pretty simple and involves plugging values into the equation. When I looked at my teacher's work he says that through a bunch of algebraic manipulations we get that equation, but I was hoping someone would actually show what those manipulations were.

Problem: A homebuyer wishes to take out a mortgage of $100,000 for a 30-year period. What monthly payment is required if the interest is (a) 9% , (b) 10% , (c) 12%.

Equation I used: $$ M= \frac {Ar(1+r)^n}{(1+r)^n-1}$$

A is the mortgage amount. r is the interest rate and n is 360 which is the 12 months X 30 years for the total amount of payments.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Are you sure about the equation you wrote ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Not really. It was something that I found in my textbook and it seemed right so I tried it out inside the problem... I could be completely off and will have to do the problem over. The whole issue I'm having is the equation and how to derive it.

Comment: Check the formula; the formula for EMI often used is $$ (A r /12)/( 1- (1+r)^{-n}) $$

Comment: That looks wrong, if only because that equation could be simplified to $M=Ar(1+r)$.

Comment: I think that the formula should be $$M= \frac {Ar(1+r)^n}{(1+r)^n-1}$$

Comment: Yes, I too think so.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes I had it wrong. The formula you have is correct. Do you where it is derived algebraically from?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_loan , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_calculator , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-rate_mortgage